# If path "**" exist, login url redirects wrongly to it

Tags: angular, redirect, path

I have the following Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: InicioComponent},
  { path: "auth", loadChildren:"../app/components/auth/auth.module#AuthModule"},
  { path: "perfil", canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProfileComponent},
  /*other paths here*/
  { path: "bruto", component: CalcBrutoComponent,canActivate: [RoleGuard], data: {expectedRole: 'Administrador'}  },
  { path: "pdf", canActivate: [RoleGuard], component: SignAndSendComponent,data: {expectedRole: 'Administrador'} },
  { path: "**", component: Page404Component}
];
```

And for reference, the one used in /auth (auth.module):

```
const routes: Routes =[
{path: 'registro',component:RegisterComponent},
{path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes),FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
    exports: [RouterModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule]
  })
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

I have it this way because I started it following a tutorial. I don't understand the advantage of having routes in a child file. Anyway, the issue is that as is, if I insert the route */login*, it redirects to the path of "**".

If I delete the "**" path line, then it redirects correctly to login. I wonder what's the issue and how can I have both login working and a ** path for 404 pages.

**ADDED** auth.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module'
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component'
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component'
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Using Angular 8.2.14.

Comment: Please add the content of your AuthModule file (and which angular version are you using?)

Comment: Added the file asked, thanks.

Comment: With the version 8 of Angular, you should declare the imported AuthModule with the new syntax : `loadChildren: () => import('../app/components/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule )`

Comment: @GérômeGrignon This is not syntactical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is redirecting to 404 because you are using lazy loading method to init component. So For auth module path will be /auth/login.

Other components will be loaded as per your current code because for that you've not used a lazy loading method.

Comment: Do you mean that in auth-routing.module.ts, I change 
path: 'login' to path: '/auth/login' ?

Comment: Not that, I mean your path for login or register will be /auth/login and /auth/register, as per your current routing code.

Comment: Try auth/login and check if login component is loaded or not!

Comment: this is correct, it seems to be working. I'll now have to change it everywhere. Thank you.

Comment: If possible, could you explain me why or what is the advantage of having a path calling a child path as in auth -> login & register? Why not having them all under the same file?

Comment: I think In the tutorial which you follow there are some requirements to have auth components and other components separately. like in the auth module you don't need navbar or sidebar while after login in the dashboard you need both at a time. This is totally based on the requirements of the project. You can get lots of other examples also to set routing.

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to have in data(expectedrole) more than one option so the user of different roles can access? I.e. "Administrator", "role2"

Comment: I'm not sure if you can pass array over there or not but you can use it like data: { tutorial: "1", tutorial_type: "dashboard" }.